# Android TV (Leanback) App: Toggle/switch for GuidedStepSupportFragment

Tags: android, television, leanback

In an Android TV (leanback) app, the user should be able to toggle a simple switch/checkbox in the GuidedStepSupportFragment. There are several input types, text, number, datetime, email and so on - but none for boolean/toggle.

How can I add a toggle into the guided steps? The user should be simply be able to toggle the option on or off. The onboarding fragment that I used before did not even offer proper options at all, just some showcasing.